# Count number of occurrences in a column and provide a summary in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to create a Excel formula to retrieve the value of each cell in a column and display a count for each occurrence in another cell while separated by comma.

For example:

Column data looks like this:

```
a
a
b
b
c
d
e
e
e
```

Desired output in another cell:

```
a(2), b(2), c(1), d(1), e(3)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you plan to have a fixed list of a, b, c, d, and e (where you type in a separate formula for each, and concatenate)? Or is this a one-time, follow a few steps to remove dupes, and then calculate counts? Or ok to use a quick macro to copy to clipboard or paste into a selected cell?

Comment: The fixed list column is random and not fixed.  The formula should work with whatever value presented in the column.  Ideally would like to see if it's possible with formula first before using a macro.

Comment: Only non-macro way is to follow some manual steps. Copy your result set into another column, then Data > Remove Duplicates. Add a COUNTIF formula to count the occurrances of the de-duped element against the original column. Finally you concatenate that. You could also do a pivot table first to get the counts by type.

Comment: Simply use PIVOT table and do whatever you want with the PIVOT result.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is countif.  Where A1:A9 is your range you are searching.

Multiple steps are required.

1. Create a row for each letter.  i.e. so they are stacked one on top of another. (see image)

   =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("a(",COUNTIF(A1:A9,"a"),")")
   =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("b(",COUNTIF(A1:A9,"b"),")")
   =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("c(",COUNTIF(A1:A9,"c"),")")
   =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("d(",COUNTIF(A1:A9,"d"),")")
   =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("e(",COUNTIF(A1:A9,"e"),")")

[image]

2. Concatenate values together on a single line use this.

   =CONCATENATE(A12,",",A13,",",A14,",",A15,",",A16)

[image]

Comment: But doesn't concatenate results in single cell

Comment: This close to what I'm looking for but the value in the column is not known and would need to be presented in the single cell.

Comment: Additional padding i.e. white space could be added to step #2's concatenation string to make it look exactly like your result set.

Comment: @Charles: thanks for the assist but the a,b,c,d is not a known value so can't use that within the COUNTIF formula to filter on.  The column data is random.

Comment: Looks like good example for known data. If you don't know the data, you'll either have to follow a manual process or write a macro function you can use as a formula with range as parameter, then use probably a dictionary to count the occurrances of the elements as you iterate over all cells in the range.

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot Table to select a single instance of each and count occurrences. A formula in D2 copied down to suit to concatenate and format the PT output:

```
=IF(OR(B2="Grand Total",B2=""),"",B2&"("&C2&")")
```

A formula in E3 copied down to suit to concatenate and format the individual rows from above:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D1),D2,E1&", "&D2)
```

Where ColumnA changes the PT would require refreshing.

[image: SO28598385 example]

Comment: Thanks but trying to avoid using a Pivot Table and requiring a refresh.  As Jason suggested, I think a macro may be the only way to achieve this.